# [Pytorch]Seek for a vectorised implementation

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Here is my code, 'x' is a regular CNN weight with size: (out_c, in_c, k_h, k_w) where **out_c** is also the number of CNN kernel. **lb**(lower bound) and **ub** (upper bond) are two predefined 1D numpy array with length **out_c**.

The task is to make sure that the value of all CNN kernel weights are within the range defined by **lb** and **ub** (i.e. **lb[i]** < **x[i, :, :, :]** < **ub[i]**, 0 <= **i** < **out_c**) by clipping all the outliers.
Besides, I need to keep the mask of outliers for other usage.

However, I cannot find a fully vectorised solution such that no for loop is involved. I'm using Pytorch 0.3.1, is there any method to make this code segment fully vectorised (get rid of for loop)? Thanks.

```
N = x.size(0) # number of cnn kernel
lower_mask = []
upper_mask = []
for i in range(N):
    lower_mask.append(x[i] < lb.tolist()[i])
    upper_mask.append(ub.tolist()[i] < x[i])
    x[i].clamp_(lb.tolist()[i], ub.tolist()[i])
lower_mask = torch.stack(lower_mask).cuda()
upper_mask = torch.stack(upper_mask).cuda()
```